# ASP.NET Dynamic Radiobutton - How to add validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, radio-button

At the moment I have something like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEventsList" DataSourceID="srcQuestionList" runat="server"> 
<ItemTemplate>

<td><span><%# Eval("orderBy").ToString()%>)</span></td>

<td><%# Eval("question").ToString()%></td>

<td><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" /></td>

<td><input name="question<%# Eval("orderBy").ToString()%>" type="radio" id="True" value="True" class="styled" /></td>

<td><input name="question<%# Eval("orderBy").ToString()%>" type="radio" id="False" value="False" class="styled" /></td> 
</tr>

</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code behind I capture the values as `Request.Form("question1")` for example and this all works fine.

Now I am wondering how to add validation to this, I think I have to apply changes to a `RadioButton` control but I can't see how I could add my dynamic `RadioButton` names in there with my id from stored procedure.

Also I would like to add the validation to the top of the screen as a validation summary.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Validation Server Controls](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp).

Comment: Yes I know I have to use Validation Controls.

As I stated in my question I was asking how to move from

<input name="question<%# Eval("orderBy").ToString()%>" type="radio" id="True"  value="True" class="styled"  />

To an asp radiobutton. I.e im not sure how to add validation to dynamic contr

Comment: I would suggest you get away from rendering your control like that, and instead do it all in the code-behind by create an instance of the control and adding it to a placeholder's Controls collection.

Comment: I second Kon. Creating a control from the code-behind and adding it to a container would give you option to set a lot of properties at runtime.